# Loop through to copy multiple outlook attachments type mismatch error

Tags: vba, outlook

I trying to loop through the message to copy multiple attachments, but no success, i'm getting 13 - type mismatch error!!!

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

my code is as follows,

```
Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    'Only act if it's a MailItem
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
        Set Msg = item


        'Set folder to save in.
        Dim olDestFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
        Dim Att As String
        Dim i As Integer
        'location to save in.  Can be root drive or mapped network drive.
        Const attPath As String = "C:\Users\pkshahbazi\Documents\EmailAttachments\"
        i = 0
        'save attachment
        Set myAttachments = item.Attachments
        If Msg.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
            For Each myAttachments In Msg.Attachments
                Att = myAttachments.item(i).DisplayName
                myAttachments.item(i).SaveAsFile attPath & Att
                'mark as read
                i = i + 1
            Next myAttachments
            Msg.UnRead = False
        End If
    End If

ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is raising the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an indexed loop over an iterable collection (myAttachments) which is unnecessary. It is not the source of the error, but the error I see is related to your iteration:

You're getting a mismatch error because you're doing:

```
For each myAttachments in Msg.Attachments
   '...
Next
```

You have already assigned `myAttachments` as `Msg.Attachments` and it is of type `Outlook.Attachments`.  This is an iterable collection, but you need to iterate using an `Outlook.Attachment` type variable.

```
Dim olAttch as Outlook.Attachment
```

Then, modify your loop like (untested):

```
    Set myAttachments = Msg.Attachments
        For Each olAttch In myAttachments
            Att = olAttch.DisplayName
            olAttch.SaveAsFile attPath & Att
        Next olAttch
        Msg.UnRead = False
```

Comment: That was helpful!!! i'm able to copy the multiple attachments now. What if I want to delete the attachments after saving them, i put the line olAttch.delete before Next OlAttch statement but not getting the desired result it breaks after processing only the one attachment.

Comment: what do you mean "it breaks"? Is there an error message? If so, what error? If not, please describe what it is doing and how that is not satisfactory.

Comment: there isn't any error message, it just delete the very first attachment after copying it but not go for the second attachment to work on! it just went to the end sub
Below is the snippet

   Set myAttachments = Msg.Attachments
        For Each olAttch In myAttachments
            Att = olAttch.DisplayName
            If Right(olAttch.FileName, 3) = "zip" Then
            olAttch.SaveAsFile attPath & Att
            olAttch.Delete
            End If
        Next olAttch
    Msg.UnRead = False

What i figured out that it olAttch.delete statement confuses the for each loop. Any Idea!!!

Comment: This looks like it should be a separate question please. it is nearly impossible to read code when it's placed in the comments here.  If you ask a new question, I'd be happy to take a look -- and it will very likely be seen by others, who can also help.

Comment: Thank! I'm raising the separate question for that. Sorry for the inconvenience...

Comment: No problem! Unless follow-ups are specifically related to the original question, they should usually be given as new questions, this is so they will receive more views from other users and so you will be more likely to get help.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing two different kinds of loops. [For Each...Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264596%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and [For...Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251601%28v=office.14%29.aspx) statements have different structures. You may want to read the documentation and examples in the above linked reference.

In a For Each loop you don't have a counter variable tracking the index. It automatically retrieves each item from the collection for you.

In a For loop you have a counter variable that increases for you, you don't have to increment it.
(e.g. `i = i + 1`)
However if you are accessing a collection you must retrieve the current item yourself.
(e.g. `myAttachments.Item(i)`, or you can use the shorter equivalent syntax of `myAttachments(i)` as that the `.Item` is implied in VBA)

Here is a working example that prints the file names for the currently active message's attachments to the Immediate window using each type of for loop.

```
Public Sub TestAttachments()
    Dim message As MailItem
    Dim myAttachment As Attachment
    Dim i As Long

    Set message = ThisOutlookSession.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    Debug.Print "For Each...Next"
    For Each myAttachment In message.Attachments
      Debug.Print "Filename: " & myAttachment.FileName
    Next myAttachment

    Debug.Print "For...Next Statement"
    For i = 1 To message.Attachments.Count
      Set myAttachment = message.Attachments(i)
      Debug.Print "Index: " & i & " Filename: " & myAttachment.FileName
    Next i
End Sub
```

As you can see, the For Each loop is far simpler. However the For loop can give you a bit more control and information when accessing indexed collections. Usually you will want to use the For Each loop.

Also note, there is some confusion in the terminology used for collections in VBA. There are multiple different kinds of collections. There are also [Collection objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251465%28v=office.14%29.aspx), which are a type of collection but not the only type of collection.