# Saving outlook attachment locally via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am currently working on a project, and I am having some trouble saving email attachments locally.

I currently have an outlook rule set up that directs all relevant emails to an Outlook folder. I want to programatically pull all of those email attachments, and save them all into one folder on my local machine.

How do I go about pulling the attachments into a specified location? Thanks!

Comment: This might help, basically `For Each myAttachment In item.Attachments` https://stackoverflow.com/q/18447097/2727437

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43646264/4539709

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the code below:

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "c:\temp"
     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
End Sub
```

For more information, please see [automatically Save outlook attachment](https://superuser.com/questions/884079/automatically-save-outlook-attachment)