# Auto Save Email Attachment

Tags: vba, outlook

I need a simple code to save a file that is received by email every hour - I want to save it to a folder on the desktop under the same name whenever saved.

So far I have the following:

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
```

Comment: you want a VBA code to save a file once an hour?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving outlook attachment locally via VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51830119/saving-outlook-attachment-locally-via-vba)

Answer (score 0):

To handle incoming emails you need to hook into the [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event of the `Applicaiton` class. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. For users with an Exchange Server account (non-Cached Exchange Mode or Cached Exchange Mode), the event will fire only for messages that arrive at the server after Outlook has started. The event will not fire for messages that are synchronized in Cached Exchange Mode immediately after Outlook starts, nor for messages that are already on the server when Outlook starts in non-Cached Exchange Mode.

After retrieving the incoming email you can save attachments to a disk:

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "c:\temp"
     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
End Sub
```