# List the attached documents in the email body

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that works fine and it attaches all the files in one folder.
I need the code to list the names of the attachments in the email body.
Part of the code below:

```
Dim folder As String
folder = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("B1").Value
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\\" & folder)
Set myAttachments = newEmail.Attachments
For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
myAttachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\\" & folder & "\\" & oFile.Name
Next oFile
```

What should I add to this?

Comment: let me know if this shows the problem: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447097/loop-through-to-copy-multiple-outlook-attachments-type-mismatch-error)

Comment: FYI in VBA there's no need to escape a backslash in a string - `"\"` is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```vb
Dim oFSO As Object, ofolder As Object, sFiles As String
Dim oFile As Object, fldr As String

'...
'...

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

fldr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("B1").value

Set ofolder = oFSO.GetFolder(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & fldr)

For Each oFile In ofolder.Files
    newEmail.Attachments.Add oFile.Path   ' no need to concatenate the path...
    sFiles = sFiles & vbCrLf & oFile.Path '<< build the list of files
Next oFile

'# now add sFiles to `newMail` message body #
```